# Usql - Job failed due to internal system error - NM_CANNOT_LAUNCH_JM

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I get the following system error,

Error in Activity: [{"errorId":"E_SYSTEM_NM_NMCANNOTLAUNCHJM"
,"name":"NM_CANNOT_LAUNCH_JM"
,"severity":"Error"
,"source":"System"
,"component":"NM"
,"message":"Job failed due to internal system error."
,"details":""
,"description":"","resolution":"","helpLink":"","innerError":null}].

The error is not intermittent. All it does is copy a file from one location to another. It says internal system error - Any ideas?

Following is my Usql script,

```
DECLARE @in string = "20160229";
DECLARE @year string = "2016";
DECLARE @month string = "02";
DECLARE @day string = "29";
DECLARE @fileSource string = "/Outputs/folder1/" + @year + @"/" + @month + @"/" + @day + @"/file." + @in;

@rs0 =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 string
    FROM @fileSource
    USING Extractors.Csv();

@rs1 =
    SELECT col1,
           col2,
           col3,
           @in AS Date
    FROM @rs0

DECLARE @fileDestination string = "/Outputs/folder2/TEST.csv";

OUTPUT @rs1
TO @fileDestination
USING Outputters.Text( quoting : false, delimiter : '|');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this same issue today on my activity that was running fine previously. But after an hour, it automatically resolved. It looks like some internal service issue. Try again, I hope it will be resolved for you!

Answer (score 0):

It was an intermittent service issue that we are investigating.

UPDATE: The issue has been resolved. Thanks for the report.